# How to write graphQL query from react using fetch api which support pagination?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, fetch, graphene-django

### Information:

- I am using graphene-Django based backed
- Using Relay Node-based query

### Tasks that I can perform:

- Write REST-based CRUD operations using fetch API in react.
- Simple GraphQL queries that involve fetching a list or single item from the server.
- Able to write GraphQL queries on GraphiQL

### Want to do the following:

- fetch a list of items from the server with pagination, that fetches say 10 items and the option to go to the first page, last page, Prev Page, and Next Page.
- few examples would help

Comment: Does the server support pagination?

Comment: yes, it supports. It returns Pageinfo object which contains hasNext, hasPrev, startCursor, endCursor. which can be used to fetch next and previous page.

Comment: @madflow could you please give some directions to solve it.

Comment: I not quite sure where you are stuck... It is all pretty much documented. For example: https://graphql.org/learn/pagination/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solved by looking into various documentation, blogs, and my current requirement as:

```
const Post = (props) => {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])
  const [offset, setOffset] = useState(0)
  const [hasPrev, setHasPrev] = useState(false)
  const [hasNext, setHasNext] = useState(false)
  const pageSize = 10

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadData = () => {
      setLoading(true)
      const requestOptions = getGraphqlRequestOptions(pageSize, offset)
      fetch(graphql_url, requestOptions)
        .then(response => {
          setLoading(false)
          return response.json()
        })
        .then(data => {
          setHasNext(data.data.allPosts.pageInfo.hasNextPage)
          setPosts(data.data.allPosts.edges)
          setHasPrev(offset !== 0)
        })
    }
    loadData()
  }, [offset]);

  const handleNextClick = () => {
    setOffset(offset + pageSize)
  };
  const handlePrevClick = () => {
    setOffset(offset - pageSize)
  };
  useEffect(()=> {
    document.title = "MyTitle"
    setOffset(0)
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      ... code to display table
      <div className="row mb-5">
        <Button 
          variant="outline-primary"
          className="col-1 me-auto"
          disabled={!(hasPrev || isLoading)}
          size="sm" block
          onClick={!isLoading ? handlePrevClick : null}
        >
          {isLoading ?  'Loading...' : 'Previous'}
        </Button>
        <Button 
          className="col-1 ms-auto"
          disabled={!(hasNext || isLoading)}
          onClick={!isLoading ? handleNextClick: null}
          variant="outline-primary" size="sm" block
        >
          {isLoading ?  'Loading...' : 'Next'}
        </Button>
      </div>
    </>
  }
```

I was stuck because there were many options and no concrete example to implement this.
For example:

- We can use:

  1. `query{allPosts(first:10, after:"last cursor"){pageInfo{hasPrevPage hasNextPage startCursor endCursor} edge{node{...}}}`
  2. `query{allPosts(first:10, offset:0){}} // currently used`
  3. `query {allPosts(first:10, before:'start cursor'
  4. All above queries with `last:10` instead of first:10, etc.
- Beside this it returns a PageInfo object having `hasNextPage, hasPrevPage, startCursor, endCursor`.

  - It was giving informations that were hard to understand
  - Using query (1) i.e. with `first` and `after` option, `hasPrevPage` was always `false`
  - Using query(3) i.e. with `before` option, `hasNextPage` was always `false`
  - So need to track whether the Next and Prev page exists was difficult.